# CakePHP Image Upload and Resizing/Cropping

Tags: cakephp, image-uploading, cakephp-2.4

I am looking for a goof and flexible Image Upload and Resizing plugin for the Lastest version of CakePHP

1. Upload Image based on MimeType
2. Check the Width and Height min/max
3. Able to Resize and Crop Center the Image to give max image visibility when cropped
4. Renaming File names
5. Specifying Custom Folders depending on the Model and relations.

Comment: Search, it was many times

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage

Read the readme.md, it can do all you want, 5. will require you to add your own event listener to allow custom folders over convention (not recommended any way). The develop branch has some more and better structured documentation as well. [This page is about the image processing part of it](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage/blob/develop/Docs/Documentation/Image-Storage-And-Versioning.md). It comes with unit tests as well and is tested from [2.0 up to 2.5](https://travis-ci.org/burzum/FileStorage) (upcoming version at this moment).

The [UploadValidationBehavior](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage/blob/master/Model/Behavior/UploadValidatorBehavior.php) will take care of the validation you want. In the case of validating image size, the ImageStorage model implements a method for that.

Comment: wow. wondering how come i didnt come across this plugin. can i store images from one model into a single folder of that model name?

Comment: Read the documentation. The plugin has *one* table to keep track of all files. All other models use associations, either hasMany, hasOne or HABTM to access this model. The table keeps track of all files and meta data like mime type, size... User hasOne Avatar for example. Avatar extends ImageStorage. You'll have to fill the model field of Avatar with "User" and configure whatever image operations you want to do on it. See https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage/blob/develop/Docs/Documentation/Image-Storage-And-Versioning.md

Comment: lol, I even do tent pegging for fun, as far as I know this is popular in India. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_pegging

Comment: hehe yeah :D which color is ur horse? i think we shouldnt be chatting about horses here :P

Comment: No. ;) There is a photo of him in the fixture folder of the plugin used for tests. While speaking of tests, fixing them in the develop branch right now, found an issue.

Comment: was expecting a black stallion :P he is amazing :D do u ride him every day?

Comment: is there anyway i can save the files to the respective models instead of a single table?

Comment: No, this works against the architecture and idea of the plugin. Read the readme.md. IMO it's wrong to store a file, which is a separate entity, directly in a table of a model. And why would you want to do that? There is no reason to do so. The plugin abstracts it properly and you can still get one or many files per model.

Comment: sorry i meant the reference to a file in the db. not the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
function upload_image($data, $id) {
        $data['photo'] = $data['image_path'];
        unset($data['image_path']);
        $upData = array();
        if ($this->fnIsNotNull($data['photo']) && $data['photo']['error'] == 0) {
            $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            $optionsUpload = array('org' => true, "thumbs" => array("width" => 270, "height" => 180));
            $fileUploaded = fileUpload($data['photo'], $data['id'] . "_category", CATEGORY_IMG_DIR, $allowedExts, $optionsUpload);
            if (isset($fileUploaded['success']) && fnIsNotNull($fileUploaded['success'])) {
                $upData = $fileUploaded['success'][0]['filename'];
            }
        }
        if (isset($id) && count($upData)) {
            $oldData = $this->get($id);
            $remvoeImg = $oldData->photo;
            $oldData->photo = $upData;
            $res = $this->save($oldData);
            if ($res && !empty($upData) && !empty($remvoeImg)) {
                @unlink(CATEGORY_IMG_DIR . $remvoeImg);
                @unlink(CATEGORY_IMG_DIR . "thumbs/" . $remvoeImg);
            }
            return $res;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use  : [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/)

Install:

```
 php composer.phar require intervention/image
```

Code:

```
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');
$img->crop(100, 100, 25, 25);
```

Comment: First this should be a model task, not component, second this plugin does not take care of keeping track of the file references nor does it keep track of the versions it generated. It's a simple image resizer, no unit tests, the code does not follow conventions, not even the file is correctly named.

Comment: can this resize and crop sir?

Comment: Yes @HarshaMV you can resize for the crop i don't know. Observance of the Conventions in my case is not good, I admit, but the mission is filled with this snippet